# Why get_posts with the same arguments retrieves different results in different pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am having some difficulties understanding how get_posts() internally works. I have the following code in both my archive-product.php (WooCommerce) and in portfolio-page.php (page template):

```
<?php

  $argsTest = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'acf-field',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order title',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'suppress_filters'  => false,
    'acf_field_key'   => 'field_544e9db1d8f54'
  );

  $results = new WP_Query( $argsTest );
  echo $results->request;
?>
```

Which returns the following SQL string and results for portfolio-page.php:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'acf-field' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND wp_posts.post_name = 'field_544e9db1d8f54'  ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 1

Result:

ID
----
2423
```

And in my archive-product.php:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','catalog')) ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 20

Result:

ID
----
2534
----
2533
----
2536
----
2537
----
```

(those are product id's, which I don't get why)

What I am trying to achieve is a bit more complicated than this but I wanted to put things in a clear way, however if that helps to clarify the propose of it, this is what I am actually trying to do:

Using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin, I am trying to `get_field('portfolio_items', woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'));` (which relates to a repeater field in the admin)

And for some reason I am not getting the expected results which should be a list of objects, instead I am getting a string with the number of current items in the repeater field (admin) `string '4'`.

I expected any page to get the same results with the same query, and that is way I am assuming that is making my `get_field()` function to return a string instead o an array of objects.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ might hold answers if you don't get one here.

Comment: Oh cool! I didn't know about wordpress.stackexchange.com. Is there a way to move my question over there?

Comment: Ask for it to be migrated, or just re-post it there I suppose?

Comment: Make sure you use `wp_reset_query()` before you run your custom query - I would also check that `$post = null;` as well as I found queries can inherit existing conditions dependant upon where you run them as well.